# How do I add values to TreeView?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a code of tree view on qml:

```
Item {
width: 899
height: 471
TreeView {
    x: 215
    y: 161
    width: 470
    height: 150
    headerVisible: true
    frameVisible: false

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "File Name"
        role: "fileName"
        width: 200
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Size"
        role: "size"
        width: 70
    }

    TableViewColumn{
        title: "Last Change"
        role: "lastChange"
        width: 200
    }

}
```

}

How do i add values to the red squares in the picture below?
I've been looking on youtube and documentation and hardly could understand anything that relates to that.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `model` in `TreeView`.

```
model: ListModel {
    id: fileModel

    ListElement {
        fileName: "myfile"
        size: "1KB"
        lastChange: "yesterday"
    }
    ListElement {
        fileName: "yourfile"
        size: "1MB"
        lastChange: "today"
    }
    ListElement {
        fileName: "otherfile"
        size: "1GB"
        lastChange: "tomorrow"
    }
}
```

Appending row to model.

```
fileModel.append({
    fileName: "anotherfile",
    size: "1TB",
    lastChange: "another day"});
```

[Quick try](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools/qml-online-declarative-coding-app)

Comment: Where did you find that? I searched for hours for that?

Comment: I saw `TreeView` inherits `BasicTableView`. `TableView` also inherits it. So I thought maybe `TableView` examples works on `TreeView` too. Then I just tried it. Plus I had quite experience with `ListView`s.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is from C++. You create your model there, from scratch by subclassing from QAbstractItemModel or by filling a QStandardItemModel with nodes. Then, you make that model available to QML, for instance by setting it as a context property. Then you bind the model property of TreeView to that model from C++.

Please note that QtQuickControls 1, which features TreeView, is not generally recommended for serious use. It is quite inefficient and not really maintained any more.

Comment: I am not usin C++, using python.

Comment: You might have mentioned that in your question, but it doesn't really matter. Same thing applies. Just replace C++ above with Python.